# What is the best way to store an AES encryption key?

Tags: java, tomcat, encryption, key-storage

We use Tomcat for our java web application. There is a properties file under WEB-INF folder.

AES encryption will be used to generate key and encrypt password. The encrypted password will be stored in the properties file. Where should be the encryption key stored? Is it a good idea to put the key and the encrypted password in the same properties file? Or should the key be stored outside of the 'webapps' directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On windows, you can use the Registry and DPAPI. Using the registry does suck, but its a necessary pain if you want to go for absolute security, and leverage the Operating System to store valuable data.

On other OS X, you can make use of the Keychain.

On linux, I would use file permissions to secure the file.

What you are proposing:

> Is it a good idea to put the key and the encrypted password in the same properties file?

Is like storing your money in a safe, then writing the combination to the safe on a stickynote and sticking the note on the safe. All you've done is inconvienced the thief, but not added any meaningful level of security.

If the property file is secure enough to house an encryption key, then you can store passwords in it, in plaintext.

Comment: Is the registry really secure enough to store a Key? can't I just Regedit and search out YourOrgName and peruse the data freely? (Would be a PITA to walk the registry tho)

Comment: Good question, no the registry is not a good place to store sensitive data in plaintext. However, using Windows DPAPI, you could secure the key, then write the encrypted value to the registry. DPAPI itself is a system level API that credentials from the authenticated user sessions to encrypt the value.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered the KeyStore class in the Java API. It's a part of Sun's Java Cryptography Architecture.

Comment: I believe you can only store public/private keypairs (asymetric keys) in the standard keystore. Not AES symmetric keys.

There is a keystore impl that allows symmetric keys: http://khylo.blogspot.com/2009/12/keytool-keystore-cannot-store-non.html

Answer (score 0):

I have following suggestions,

1. Don't store the key in the WAR. We leave the responsibility of securing the key to each installation. On production, we can actually secure it by storing the key files on a smartcard.
2. Make sure your keys are versioned so you can rotate it regularly.
3. Store pass-phrases to generate the key, instead of the raw key material. This makes it easier to add new keys (you don't have to worry about algorithm or keysize etc). It also adds some obscurity.

Answer (score 0):

I would follow this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-secret-key-to-string) and convert the SecretKey  to Base64 encode string. This Key along with Initialization Vector can then be saved to any database different from the active transactional database, and later fetched in other services for decrypting. Would use an alias for each key generated, so they can then be properly tagged.